# Book recommendation for hydrodynamics of bubbles, drops, and particles

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, materials, chemical-engineering, biomechanics

I am wondering if someone could please recommend to me some references on the topic of hydrodynamics of bubbles, drops, and particles, preferably in the context of complex and bio fluids.

I am currently reading the book $\textit{Bubbles, Drops, and Particles}$ by Clift, which surveys the field well. I am interested in transport, deformation, and bursting of bubbles and applications of such in biomedical related topics, such as drug delivery and transport in human circulation system.

My background includes general fluid mechanics (viscous flow in context of both mechanical engineering and applied math), PDEs, classical differential geometry, and pathophysiology, yet I am new to this field of complex fluids and interfacial phenomena. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: It's an extremely rich topic. Be prepared to read many papers. Depending on what you are doing, a dive into theories of surface tension may be appropriate - it is not a settled area of science. Even the "simpler" stuff like multiphase capillary flows (with the interface spanning the entire channel) was only really figured out in the early/mid 2000s. Unfortunately as a product / systems engineer I don't have good book recommendation, would be curious myself.

Comment: btw book recommendation requests are technically off limits at StackExchange, but +1 anyway because it's an important and not-enough-understood field (IMO)